# Descriptions of Boto3 ClientMethods

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to use Boto3's `generate_presigned_url()`. The method requires a ClientMethod and parameters to go with that ClientMethod. However, the Boto3 documentation doesn't seem to have any list of ClientMethods with their respective parameters. Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`ClientMethod` is just the string name of one of the methods on the client object you are calling `generate_presigned_url()` on, e.g. for the S3 client the methods are listed here [S3.Client](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client). E.g. using the `'get_object'` method on the S3 client looks like:

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
url = client.generate_presigned_url('get_object', 
                                    Params={'Bucket': <name>,'Key': <object>}, 
                                    ExpiresIn=86400)
```

Comment: It can be `client.get_object()` or `client.generate_presigned_url(ClientMethod= 'get_object' ) ` .. Its very confusing. One more is `list_buckets`. How many different `ClientMethod` in `client.generate_presigned_url` exist?